# Run Google Chrome application from url

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

I am trying to run Google Chrome application using a url, I tried the following:

```
chrome-extension://gfkmokjholoinfcnlolbjfaokmoegeoh/
```

But it didn't work, as I get:

```
chrome-extension://invalid/
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

```
chrome-extension://pnhechapfaindjhompbnflcldabbghjo/html/nassh.html
```

Use full path if you know.

Answer (score 1):

You have to list the resources you are accessing in [web_accessible_resources](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/web_accessible_resources) in your manifest.