# Run chrome application from a web site button

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, web, google-chrome-app

I have a requirement to launch a **chrome application** from a web page **button click**. I have found the following resources,'

- [Run Google Chrome application from url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26956702/run-google-chrome-application-from-url)
- [Activate chrome app from web page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19519277/activate-chrome-app-from-web-page)
- [How can I launch a Chrome Packaged App through javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17097941/how-can-i-launch-a-chrome-packaged-app-through-javascript)

Which suggests to use **externally_connectable** and **url_handlers** but doesn't seem to work. Is there a proper way I could launch a chrome application via **button click on web** page by calling the **chrome app extension id**?.

I am new to this field and any help from you experts would be greatly appreciated :)

**PS**

I tried the following command on a button click on my web page,

`chrome.management.launchApp('app id');`

This resulted in an error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'launchApp' of undefined`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found how to achieve this incase someone else comes across this issue.

- in your web page **on button click** for example, include the following code,

  ```
                                                   //data passed from web to chrome app
  chrome.runtime.sendMessage('your_chrome_app_id', { message: "version" },
      function (reply) {
          if (reply) {
              if (reply.version) {
                  //log the response received from the chrome application
                  console.log(reply.version);
              }
          }
      }
   );
  ```
- in your chrome application **manifest.json** define the `externally_connectable` url/ urls as follows,

  ```
   {
    "name": "App name",
    "description": "App Desc",
    "version": "1",

    ...

    "externally_connectable": {
      "matches": ["*://localhost:*/"]
    }
  }
  ```
- In your application **background.js** setup a listener to be invoked when a message is sent from the web page as follows,

  ```
  chrome.runtime.onMessageExternal.addListener(
    function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
      if (request) {
        if (request.message) {
          if (request.message == "version") {

            //my chrome application initial load screen is login.html
            window.open('login.html');

            //if required can send a response back to the web site aswell. I have logged the reply on the web site
            sendResponse({version: '1.1.1'});
          }
        }
      }
      return true;
    });
  ```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: That's a helpful example, so upvoted. But please do not use `inline code formatting` with `\`` for text highlight. There's a _perfectly_ **versatile** ***array*** of tools to highlight text otherwise. Could you edit your question/answer to remove that formatting on non-code text?

Answer (score 1):

Hasitha's reply worked. However in the manifest file I needed to do a regex change. 
For the URL

```
localhost:3905/manager
```

obviously the externally_connectible value should be set as

```
"externally_connectable": {
    "matches": ["*://localhost:*/*"]
}
```

But for some reason, the same URL cannot be matched with

```
"externally_connectable": {
    "matches": ["*://localhost*"]
}
```

did not work. 
Generated error **Invalid match pattern '*://localhost*'**