# Launch third party chrome packed app from within chrome app

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-app

I'm trying to get my chrome packaged app to be able to launch a third party chrome app. Unfortunately, I am unable to use `chrome.management.launchApp()` because the management API is unsupported for packaged apps. I found several other answers on SO that suggest using messaging to launch the app such as the one found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31800690/run-chrome-application-from-a-web-site-button/31806110), but they all refer to launching one's own app.

Is it possible to send some message that will automatically launch the app, like this:

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage(<appId>,<launchApp>)
```

Or is there some other way to do this?